# Test driven development: Testing ssl

Tags: testing, ssl, akka

We are using the Akka framework and have recently switched our communication to being encrypted with SSL within a cluster.

It seems to be working, but I fear that we may accidentally disable it in the future developments and not notice it.

How would you go about writing a unit test that guarantees that your communication is encrypted, so that if someone moves it to being in clear we can detect it at build time?

This can be either or not akka specific, I'll be happy with both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the negative test that tries not encrypted communication. The failure will be the expected result of the such test in the encrypted communication channel. However if the encryption will omitted the test will signal that to you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on it a bit? I need to test the servers cluster internal communication to be encrypted, not the communication between the client and the server. I can startup a cluster that runs no encrypted communication, or I can start it with encrypted comms, but I can't decide how to send a message (that's taken from the startup config).

Comment: Does this mean that you can't send not encrypted message in the encrypted environment even as the unit test?

Comment: It means I have no choice about it at the time of sending. Either the conf says everything is encrypted, or everything is in clear, you just send the message and the library takes care of it. But I want to test whether my config is valid, i.e. if it's actually encrypting them.

Comment: You send the message an you don't know is encryption works or not. Then you need some listener that will receive this message (decrypted if the decryption is on). Then you need assume that this message is not decrypted and try to compare it with what you sent. If that fail this means that decryption is working. If the system is absolute black box and such listener is impossible I am not sure that you can test it.

Comment: I do believe the system is black boxed. Do you think it would be feasible / worth it to have a test that spins off a network sniffer and analyze the traffic, then sending a specific known message (something like a special string or whatnot) and check whether the sniffer picks it up?

Comment: If you can sniff the message this is already not black box system. I mean the black box system not allows to see what happens inside. You send the message as the input and receive the message as the output.  You don't know what system does. If this is not a case then the listener I mentioned should work. The network sniffing also may play listener role however the implementation may be bit complicated. Please try to find way to implement your listener inside the system.